# C - Segmentation fault (core dumped), read first N bytes from file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

I wrote some code to read first `pos` bytes from a binary file and write it into another file. Turned out I got segmentation fault when I ran it. Here is the code:

```
void outputUntillPos(const char * inFileName, const char * outFileName, int pos) {
FILE * inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r");
FILE * outFile = fopen(outFileName, "aw");

char buf[1024];
int read = 0;
int remain = pos;

do {
    if(remain <= 1024) {
        read = fread(buf, 1, pos, inFile);
    } else {
        read = fread(buf, 1, 1024, inFile);
    }

    remain -= read;
    fwrite(buf, 1, read, outFile);
    memset(buf, 0, 1024);
} while(remain > 0);
}
```

Did I get out-of-range operation here?

EDIT: Thanks to all the help, here is the edited code.

```
void outputUntillPos(const char * inFileName, const char * outFileName, int pos) {
FILE * inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r");
FILE * outFile = fopen(outFileName, "aw");

char buf[1024];
int read = 0;
int remain = pos;

if((inFile != NULL) && (outFile != NULL)) {
    do {
        if(remain <= 1024) {
            read = fread(buf, 1, remain, inFile);
        } else {
            read = fread(buf, 1, 1024, inFile);
        }

        remain -= read;
        fwrite(buf, 1, read, outFile);
        memset(buf, 0, 1024);
    } while(remain > 0 && read > 0);
}

fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);
}
```

Comment: Where do you close the files if you do close them?

Comment: Step 1. You didn't check the files opened. If they don't it is sure to segfault.

Comment: When the remaining amount of bytes to read (in variable `remain`) becomes less that `1024`, you for some reason attempt to read `pos` bytes. Why `pos`??? You are supposed  to read `remain` bytes on the last iteration.

Comment: @Jacobr365 The outFile/inFile should be closed after the read/write is done, you are saying that's the problem?

Comment: @AnT Ohhhh, that's the problem!

Comment: You are supposed to close the file with fclose(). Also you don't check to see if the file is already open.

Comment: You also aren't checking that inFile has at least pos bytes in it

Comment: Yes, `while(remain > 0 && read > 0)`

Comment: That does not look like C++. Do not add unrelated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `remain` becomes <= 1024 and the `if` portion of the block is entered, you're reading in `pos` bytes, which if it's greater that 1024 will write past the end of the buffer.  That's what causes the segfault.

You want to use `remain` here instead:

```
if(remain <= 1024) {
    read = fread(buf, 1, remain, inFile);
} else {
    read = fread(buf, 1, 1024, inFile);
}
```

Also, be sure to check the return value of `fopen`, and to `fclose(inFile)` and `fclose(outFile)` before you return.

Answer (score 0):

When the remaining amount of bytes to read (in variable `remain`) becomes less that `1024`, you for some reason attempt to read `pos` bytes. Why `pos`??? You are supposed to read `remain` bytes on the last iteration, not `pos` bytes.

If `pos` is greater than `1024` and the input file still has extra data, then of course you will overrun the buffer on that last iteration.